# Time-sensitive decoding help needed

Tags: riddle, wordplay, steganography

The African Bureau needs to know know when and where the drop will occur.  Officials have been waiting a long time for this, but on such short notice, there is no time to decode.  Please help!

Here is the full message:

> With a long tail swish and a tiny fin movement the large fish makes a small change in direction.
>   Not far to travel in this vast ocean.
>   A small boat turns a small rudder.
>   One little movement, with enormous effect, barely noticed.
>   Big eyes open wide, stare to infinity.
>
> It is taking forever.
>   Minimal hope, minimal chance.  Possible huge payoff.
>   Almost nothing changes.
>
> Does this insignificant little act mean that a whole world cares just a little?
>   Forever, forever it takes, too long to wait.
>   No time, no time.  Endless delay.
>   A quick glance, a long stare, a blink.
>
> Small ripples across the vast, vast ocean, tiny waves.
>   A lifetime, endlessly.

Comment: That was a fun one!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The drop is happening

> **in CAIRO, TUESDAY at FOUR P.M.**

In the text there are words

> hinting at the idea of being "big" or "small", "long" or "short". These can be interpreted as Morse code. (This is clued by "waiting a **long** time" and "such **short** notice".)

---

With a **long** tail swish and a **tiny** fin movement the **large** fish makes a **small** change in direction.

> C

**Not far** to travel in this **vast** ocean.

> A

A **small** boat turns a **small** rudder.

> I

One **little** movement, with **enormous** effect, **barely noticed**.

> R

**Big** eyes open **wide**, stare **to infinity**.

> O

---

It is taking **forever**.

> T

**Minimal** hope, **minimal** chance. Possible **huge** payoff.

> U

Almost nothing changes.

> E

---

Does this **insignificant** **little** act mean that a **whole** world cares just a **little**?

> F

**Forever**, **forever** it takes, **too long** to wait.

> O

**No time**, **no time**. **Endless delay**.

> U

A **quick** glance, a **long** stare, a **blink**.

> R

---

**Small** ripples across the **vast**, **vast** ocean, **tiny** waves.

> P

A **lifetime**, **endlessly**.

> M

Comment: Perfect!  Well done.